# Combine PARTITION BY and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a (mssql) table like this:

```
+----+----------+---------+--------+--------+
| id | username |  date   | scoreA | scoreB |
+----+----------+---------+--------+--------+
|  1 | jim      | 01/2020 |    100 |      0 |
|  2 | max      | 01/2020 |      0 |    200 |
|  3 | jim      | 01/2020 |      0 |    150 |
|  4 | max      | 02/2020 |    150 |      0 |
|  5 | jim      | 02/2020 |      0 |    300 |
|  6 | lee      | 02/2020 |    100 |      0 |
|  7 | max      | 02/2020 |      0 |    200 |
+----+----------+---------+--------+--------+
```

What I need is to get the best "combined" score per date. (With "combined" score I mean the best scores per user and per date summarized)

The result should look like this:

```
+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
| username |  date   | combined_score (max(scoreA) + max(scoreB)) |
+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
| jim      | 01/2020 |                                        250 |
| max      | 02/2020 |                                        350 |
+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
```

---

I came this far:
I can group the scores by user like this:

```
SELECT  
username, (max(scoreA) + max(scoreB)) AS combined_score,
FROM score_table
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY combined_score DESC
```

And I can get the best score per date with PARTITION BY like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(SELECT t.*, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY scoreA DESC) rn
FROM score_table t) as tmp
WHERE tmp.rn = 1
ORDER BY date
```

---

Is there a proper way to combine these statements and get the result I need? Thank you!

Btw. Don't care about possible ties!

Comment: I upvoted because you have a very well constructed question with examples of what you did. Good Job!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine window functions and aggregation functions like this:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT username, date, (max(scoreA) + max(scoreB)) AS combined_score,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY max(scoreA) + max(scoreB) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM score_table
      GROUP BY username, date
     ) s
ORDER BY combined_score DESC;
```

Note that `date` needs to be part of the aggregation.